# Having trouble installing NewsSentiment and RUST and sentencepiece in conda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rust, anaconda, sentencepiece

I'm trying to install NewsSentiment on anaconda, which gave me this error:

```
(pytorch) C:\Users\chenx>pip3 install newssentiment
Collecting newssentiment
  Using cached NewsSentiment-1.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (912 kB)
Collecting boto3>=1.19.7 (from newssentiment)
  Using cached boto3-1.29.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.7 kB)
Collecting gensim>=4.0.1 (from newssentiment)
  Using cached gensim-4.3.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (8.5 kB)
Collecting imbalanced-learn>=0.8.1 (from newssentiment)
  Using cached imbalanced_learn-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.3 kB)
Collecting jsonlines>=2.0.0 (from newssentiment)
  Using cached jsonlines-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
Collecting matplotlib>=3.4.3 (from newssentiment)
  Using cached matplotlib-3.8.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (5.9 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx>=2.6.3 in e:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from newssentiment) (3.1)
Collecting openpyxl>=3.0.5 (from newssentiment)
  Using cached openpyxl-3.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (249 kB)
Collecting pandas>=1.3.3 (from newssentiment)
  Using cached pandas-2.1.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (18 kB)
Collecting torch<2,>=1.7.1 (from newssentiment)
  Downloading torch-1.13.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (162.5 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 162.5/162.5 MB 10.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting regex>=2021.10.23 (from newssentiment)
  Downloading regex-2023.10.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (41 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 42.0/42.0 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.26.0 in e:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from newssentiment) (2.31.0)
Collecting sacremoses>=0.0.46 (from newssentiment)
  Downloading sacremoses-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.3 kB)
Collecting scikit-learn>=1.0.1 (from newssentiment)
  Downloading scikit_learn-1.3.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (11 kB)
Collecting spacy<3,>=2.1 (from newssentiment)
  Downloading spacy-2.3.9-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (9.1 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 9.1/9.1 MB 13.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting tabulate>=0.8.9 (from newssentiment)
  Downloading tabulate-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Collecting tqdm>=4.62.3 (from newssentiment)
  Downloading tqdm-4.66.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (57 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 57.6/57.6 kB 3.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting transformers<4,>=3.1.0 (from newssentiment)
  Using cached transformers-3.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.3 MB)
Collecting botocore<1.33.0,>=1.32.1 (from boto3>=1.19.7->newssentiment)
  Downloading botocore-1.32.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.1 kB)
Collecting jmespath<2.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from boto3>=1.19.7->newssentiment)
  Downloading jmespath-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting s3transfer<0.8.0,>=0.7.0 (from boto3>=1.19.7->newssentiment)
  Downloading s3transfer-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18.5 in e:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from gensim>=4.0.1->newssentiment) (1.26.0)
Collecting scipy>=1.7.0 (from gensim>=4.0.1->newssentiment)
  Downloading scipy-1.11.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 60.4/60.4 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Collecting smart-open>=1.8.1 (from gensim>=4.0.1->newssentiment)
  Downloading smart_open-6.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (21 kB)
Collecting joblib>=1.1.1 (from imbalanced-learn>=0.8.1->newssentiment)
  Downloading joblib-1.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.4 kB)
Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 (from imbalanced-learn>=0.8.1->newssentiment)
  Downloading threadpoolctl-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (10.0 kB)
Collecting attrs>=19.2.0 (from jsonlines>=2.0.0->newssentiment)
  Downloading attrs-23.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 61.2/61.2 kB 3.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting contourpy>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib>=3.4.3->newssentiment)
  Downloading contourpy-1.2.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib>=3.4.3->newssentiment)
  Downloading cycler-0.12.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
Collecting fonttools>=4.22.0 (from matplotlib>=3.4.3->newssentiment)
  Downloading fonttools-4.44.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (157 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 157.7/157.7 kB 9.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.3.1 (from matplotlib>=3.4.3->newssentiment)
  Downloading kiwisolver-1.4.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (6.5 kB)
Collecting packaging>=20.0 (from matplotlib>=3.4.3->newssentiment)
  Downloading packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=8 in e:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.4.3->newssentiment) (10.0.1)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.3.1 (from matplotlib>=3.4.3->newssentiment)
  Downloading pyparsing-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.1 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.7 (from matplotlib>=3.4.3->newssentiment)
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 247.7/247.7 kB 15.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting importlib-resources>=3.2.0 (from matplotlib>=3.4.3->newssentiment)
  Downloading importlib_resources-6.1.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.1 kB)
Collecting et-xmlfile (from openpyxl>=3.0.5->newssentiment)
  Using cached et_xmlfile-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
Collecting pytz>=2020.1 (from pandas>=1.3.3->newssentiment)
  Downloading pytz-2023.3.post1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (22 kB)
Collecting tzdata>=2022.1 (from pandas>=1.3.3->newssentiment)
  Downloading tzdata-2023.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (341 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 341.8/341.8 kB 20.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in e:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.26.0->newssentiment) (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in e:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.26.0->newssentiment) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in e:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.26.0->newssentiment) (1.26.18)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in e:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.26.0->newssentiment) (2023.7.22)
Collecting click (from sacremoses>=0.0.46->newssentiment)
  Downloading click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0 (from spacy<3,>=2.1->newssentiment)
  Downloading murmurhash-1.0.10-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.0 kB)
Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2 (from spacy<3,>=2.1->newssentiment)
  Downloading cymem-2.0.8-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (8.6 kB)
Collecting preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 (from spacy<3,>=2.1->newssentiment)
  Downloading preshed-3.0.9-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Collecting thinc<7.5.0,>=7.4.1 (from spacy<3,>=2.1->newssentiment)
  Downloading thinc-7.4.6-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (830 kB)
     ---------------------------------------- 830.6/830.6 kB 13.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting blis<0.8.0,>=0.4.0 (from spacy<3,>=2.1->newssentiment)
  Downloading blis-0.7.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (7.6 kB)
Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.4.0 (from spacy<3,>=2.1->newssentiment)
  Downloading wasabi-0.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=1.0.2 (from spacy<3,>=2.1->newssentiment)
  Downloading srsly-1.0.7-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (14 kB)
Collecting catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7 (from spacy<3,>=2.1->newssentiment)
  Using cached catalogue-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in e:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from spacy<3,>=2.1->newssentiment) (68.0.0)
Collecting plac<1.2.0,>=0.9.6 (from spacy<3,>=2.1->newssentiment)
  Using cached plac-1.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in e:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from torch<2,>=1.7.1->newssentiment) (4.7.1)
Collecting colorama (from tqdm>=4.62.3->newssentiment)
  Downloading colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting tokenizers==0.9.3 (from transformers<4,>=3.1.0->newssentiment)
  Using cached tokenizers-0.9.3.tar.gz (172 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in e:\anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages (from transformers<4,>=3.1.0->newssentiment) (3.9.0)
Collecting sentencepiece==0.1.91 (from transformers<4,>=3.1.0->newssentiment)
  Using cached sentencepiece-0.1.91.tar.gz (500 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting protobuf (from transformers<4,>=3.1.0->newssentiment)
  Downloading protobuf-4.25.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (541 bytes)
Collecting zipp>=3.1.0 (from importlib-resources>=3.2.0->matplotlib>=3.4.3->newssentiment)
  Downloading zipp-3.17.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib>=3.4.3->newssentiment)
  Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Downloading boto3-1.29.1-py3-none-any.whl (135 kB)
   ---------------------------------------- 135.8/135.8 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Downloading gensim-4.3.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (24.0 MB)
   ---------------------------------------- 24.0/24.0 MB 12.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Using cached imbalanced_learn-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (235 kB)
Downloading jsonlines-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.7 kB)
Downloading matplotlib-3.8.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (7.6 MB)
   ---------------------------------------- 7.6/7.6 MB 14.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading pandas-2.1.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (10.8 MB)
   ---------------------------------------- 10.8/10.8 MB 13.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading regex-2023.10.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (269 kB)
   ---------------------------------------- 269.6/269.6 kB 5.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading sacremoses-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (897 kB)
   ---------------------------------------- 897.5/897.5 kB 18.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading scikit_learn-1.3.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (9.3 MB)
   ---------------------------------------- 9.3/9.3 MB 14.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading tqdm-4.66.1-py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
   ---------------------------------------- 78.3/78.3 kB 4.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading blis-0.7.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (6.6 MB)
   ---------------------------------------- 6.6/6.6 MB 13.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading botocore-1.32.1-py3-none-any.whl (11.4 MB)
   ---------------------------------------- 11.4/11.4 MB 13.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading contourpy-1.2.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (181 kB)
   ---------------------------------------- 181.9/181.9 kB 11.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading cycler-0.12.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.3 kB)
Downloading cymem-2.0.8-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (39 kB)
Downloading fonttools-4.44.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.1 MB)
   ---------------------------------------- 2.1/2.1 MB 15.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading importlib_resources-6.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
Downloading joblib-1.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (302 kB)
   ---------------------------------------- 302.2/302.2 kB 9.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading kiwisolver-1.4.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (56 kB)
   ---------------------------------------- 56.2/56.2 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Downloading murmurhash-1.0.10-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (25 kB)
Downloading packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
   ---------------------------------------- 53.0/53.0 kB 2.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading preshed-3.0.9-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (122 kB)
   ---------------------------------------- 122.7/122.7 kB 7.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading pyparsing-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
   ---------------------------------------- 103.1/103.1 kB 5.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading pytz-2023.3.post1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (502 kB)
   ---------------------------------------- 502.5/502.5 kB 15.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading s3transfer-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
   ---------------------------------------- 79.8/79.8 kB 4.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading scipy-1.11.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (44.3 MB)
   ---------------------------------------- 44.3/44.3 MB 13.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading smart_open-6.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
   ---------------------------------------- 57.0/57.0 kB ? eta 0:00:00
Downloading srsly-1.0.7-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (358 kB)
   ---------------------------------------- 358.9/358.9 kB 11.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/81/12/fd4dea011af9d69e1cad05c75f3f7202cdcbeac9b712eea58ca779a72865/threadpoolctl-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
Downloading threadpoolctl-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Downloading click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
   ---------------------------------------- 97.9/97.9 kB 626.4 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading protobuf-4.25.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (413 kB)
   ---------------------------------------- 413.4/413.4 kB 2.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading zipp-3.17.0-py3-none-any.whl (7.4 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: sentencepiece, tokenizers
  Building wheel for sentencepiece (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [30 lines of output]
      E:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:745: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Invalid dash-separated options
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future
              versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead.

              This deprecation is overdue, please update your project and remove deprecated
              calls to avoid build errors in the future.

              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        opt = self.warn_dash_deprecation(opt, section)
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
      copying sentencepiece.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
      running build_ext
      building '_sentencepiece' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IE:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\include -IE:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpsentencepiece_wrap.cxx /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\sentencepiece_wrap.obj /MT /I..\build\root\include
      cl: ??? warning D9025 :????"/MD"(?"/MT")
      sentencepiece_wrap.cxx
      sentencepiece_wrap.cxx(2777): fatal error C1083: ????????: "sentencepiece_processor.h": No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for sentencepiece
  Running setup.py clean for sentencepiece
  Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [47 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers
      copying py_src\tokenizers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\models
      copying py_src\tokenizers\models\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\models
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\decoders
      copying py_src\tokenizers\decoders\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\decoders
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\normalizers
      copying py_src\tokenizers\normalizers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\normalizers
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\pre_tokenizers
      copying py_src\tokenizers\pre_tokenizers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\pre_tokenizers
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\processors
      copying py_src\tokenizers\processors\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\processors
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\trainers
      copying py_src\tokenizers\trainers\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\trainers
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\implementations
      copying py_src\tokenizers\implementations\base_tokenizer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\implementations
      copying py_src\tokenizers\implementations\bert_wordpiece.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\implementations
      copying py_src\tokenizers\implementations\byte_level_bpe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\implementations
      copying py_src\tokenizers\implementations\char_level_bpe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\implementations
      copying py_src\tokenizers\implementations\sentencepiece_bpe.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\implementations
      copying py_src\tokenizers\implementations\sentencepiece_unigram.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\implementations
      copying py_src\tokenizers\implementations\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\implementations      copying py_src\tokenizers\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers
      copying py_src\tokenizers\models\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\models
      copying py_src\tokenizers\decoders\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\decoders
      copying py_src\tokenizers\normalizers\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\normalizers
      copying py_src\tokenizers\pre_tokenizers\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\pre_tokenizers
      copying py_src\tokenizers\processors\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\processors
      copying py_src\tokenizers\trainers\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-39\tokenizers\trainers
      running build_ext
      running build_rust
      error: can't find Rust compiler

      If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the need for a Rust compiler.

      To update pip, run:

          pip install --upgrade pip

      and then retry package installation.

      If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tokenizers
Failed to build sentencepiece tokenizers
ERROR: Could not build wheels for sentencepiece, tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I'm not sure what "**cl: ??? warning D9025 :????"/MD"(?"/MT")
sentencepiece_wrap.cxx
sentencepiece_wrap.cxx(2777): fatal error C1083: ????????: "sentencepiece_processor.h": No such file or directory**" this is talking about, since I do have sentencepiece installed.
So instead, I tried to install RUST first, and then it gaves me this error:

```
(pytorch) C:\Users\chenx>pip3 install rust
Collecting rust
  Using cached RUST-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
Collecting pysam (from rust)
  Using cached pysam-0.22.0.tar.gz (4.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [34 lines of output]
      # pysam: cython is available - using cythonize if necessary
      # pysam: htslib mode is shared
      # pysam: HTSLIB_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS=None
      '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
      '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
      # pysam: htslib configure options: None
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "E:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "E:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "E:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\chenx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2ntp7ccq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\chenx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2ntp7ccq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\chenx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2ntp7ccq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\chenx\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-2ntp7ccq\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 442, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 82, in run_make_print_config
        File "E:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
          return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
        File "E:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\subprocess.py", line 505, in run
          with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
        File "E:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
          self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
        File "E:\Anaconda\envs\pytorch\lib\subprocess.py", line 1436, in _execute_child
          hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] \u7cfb\u7edf\u627e\u4e0d\u5230\u6307\u5b9a\u7684\u6587\u4ef6\u3002
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I'm not sure what " **FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] \u7cfb\u7edf\u627e\u4e0d\u5230\u6307\u5b9a\u7684\u6587\u4ef6\u3002**" this line meant?
I re-installed anaconda and it didn't do anything.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I can see that you are using `python 3.9`

From the *Official page of NewsSentiment* :

https://pypi.org/project/NewsSentiment/

> Requires: Python <3.9, >=3.7

**It Only supports Python 3.7 and Python 3.8**

> If you don't have Python 3.7, we
> recommend using Anaconda for setting up requirements because it is very easy

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fhamborg/NewsMTSC/main/pythoninfo.md